# Replace either of `"(.+)"` or `{(.+)}` by `\1`

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I can do

1. `{(.+)}`-->`\1`, and
2. `"(.+)"`-->`\1`, or
3. `({.+}|".+")`-->`\1`.

I would I do `{(.+)}|"(.+)"`-->`\1`?

```
$ echo "\"x\"" | sed -E 's/"(.+)"/\1/'
x
$ echo "{x}" | sed -E 's/{(.+)}/\1/'
x
$ echo "\"x\"" | sed -E 's/^(\{.+\}|".+")$/\1/' 
"x"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be

```bsh
 sed -E '/^(\{.+\}|".+")$/s/.(.+)./\1/'
```

---

Or, this:

```bsh
sed -E 's/\{(.+)\}|"(.+)"/\1\2/'
```

Or, if Perl is an option then it can be made simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```bsh
$ echo '{x}' | sed -E 's/^["{](.+)["}]$/\1/'
x
$ echo '"x"' | sed -E 's/^["{](.+)["}]$/\1/'
x
```

---

You can see in your pattern `(\{.+\}|".+")` that brackets and quotes are *inside* the capture group, when what you want to capture is *between* them.

Comment: Test with `echo '{x"'`

Comment: @they right, I was assuming the input string was either one format or the other, but of course the best regexes are those that cover most or all possible cases. Thanks.